# Rounding up hh:mm:ss.00 to hh:mm:ss

Tags: time, rounding, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to round up time (hh:mm:ss.00) in OpenOffice Calc, but to no success.

For example, I am trying to round up the following time to HH:MM:SS

```
01:41:32.69 -> 01:41:33
01:45:59.20 -> 01:46:00
01:31:48.62 -> 01:31:49
01:01:56.12 -> 01:01:57
```

I've tried using:

```
 mround(A1,1/24/60/60)
```

but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found using the ceiling function works.

Thanks for reading everyone!